# Getting Status Code 0 while running project in "Release" mode visual studio 2019 Android App with Web API

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I made a sample androd app that does nothing but calls a web api post method using RestSharp and displays string result on screen. I am testing it using android emulator of Visual Studio 2019. It works fine as long as I execute project in debug mode but when I execute it in Release mode (without making any change) it gets status code 0. Please find below method which is being called by andoid app:

```
public static string FetchDB()
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.2.200:8008/ecmiddleware/middleware/getstats");
                
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);                
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                
                if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return response.Content;
                else
                    return $"Not found \n{client.BaseUrl.AbsoluteUri}\n{DateTime.Now}\n{response.StatusCode}:{response.StatusDescription}";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

Your expert opinion to fix this issue will highly be appreciated.

Comment: Don't use  a restsharp any more. Try a httpclient. At least somebody can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Serge , Please post your suggestion as answer. I will mark it as accepted answer.